# Monitor not using native resolution on Mac

Tags: mac, display, external-display

I just got a new monitor, a Gigabyte G34WQC. Plugging it in to my Mac (2019 latest Catalina) via a HDMI -> USBC is only giving me a resolution of 2560 x 1440 not the max resolution of 3440 x 1440 of the monitor.

I've tried adjusting the frame rate via the Mac settings but the option to do so is greyed out and defaults to 60hz.

Could this be the fault of a cheap HDMI -> USBC adapter or am I missing something else?

I'm using the HDMI cable that came with the monitor.

This is the exact HDMI adapter I bought, from Amazon:
https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B08CL4Y3PJ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

This is the new display port adapter I hope will solve the issue
https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B08D6LFJXB/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Mac Model Identifier: **MacBookPro16,1**

Comment: What resolution does the adapter support?

Comment: The description of the adapter says "4K HDMI Output"

Comment: That's not quite what I asked. The adapter will likely have a table that lists the resolutions that it supports, or a specific number that lists the maximum pixels it can transmit.

Comment: Ah, sorry. There's a list of other supported resolutions and 3440x1440 does appear in that list

Comment: I've bought a display port -> usbc. I'm hoping that works

Comment: Is your adapter a standard USB "alt mode" HDMI adapter, or the less common, less compatible, more expensive, proprietary "DisplayLink" (note: -Link, not -Port) kind? With the former, the resolution is usually up to what your GPU supports. With the latter, it's whatever the proprietary DisplayLink adapter device supports.

Comment: For clarification, I've added the HDMI->USBC adapter that I am using to the question, as well as the Display port -> USBC adapter that I have just bought (arrives tomorrow)

Comment: @CarlMarkham Both devices you linked to use standard USB "alt modes" for HDMI or DisplayPort, respectively. So that's good. That means what resolution is supported is up to your Mac's hardware. You didn't mention which exact model of Mac you have, so we can't look up its specs. If you go to the Apple menu > About This Mac > System Report… > Hardware Overview > Model Identifier, and copy and paste it here (it will look something like "MacBookPro16,1"), that's the most reliable way to identify exactly which hardware you have.

Comment: Thanks @Spiff I've added it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved. I bought a Display Port to USBC and can now run the monitor in its native resolution.